# Ways to display QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencl

I'm planning to demonstrate some image processing algorithms using OpenCL and Qt.

I know I can display a QImage with QLabel.

**Is there any other way?** (more efficient, more elegant)

It would be nice, if I could show some "real time" transformation.
**Is it possible?**

Comment: `more efficient, more elegant`? What do you mean? I think QLabel is pretty simple for using with images.

Comment: @vahancho Just asking what are the possibilities. Maybe there is a special case for me (OpenCL + QImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an OpenGL context with a QGLWidget and then use OpenCL-OpenGL interchangeability. So, the image is rendered as a texture in OpenGL and computation is done in OpenCL.

Alternatively, have a look at this link http://doc.qt.digia.com/opencl-snapshot/openclgl.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use;

1. void GLWidget::paintGL() with OpenGL void

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glDrawPixels(img.width(), img.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.bits());
2. void Painter::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) with Qt painter

   QPainter painter(this);
   painter.drawImage(0,0,img,0,0,img.width(),img.height());

Answer (score 1):

The one way I know about is to subclass `QWidget`, override `paintEvent` and draw QImage using provided `QPainter`. You may also want to call `update()` on that widget explicitly if you want to update your image.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an example of this using the OpenCL/Qt interop support in [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) to apply a simple blur filter to a `QImage` using OpenCL and then display it in a Qt window.

See: https://github.com/kylelutz/compute/blob/master/example/qimage_blur.cpp